# Bootstrap: link a table row to a different image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hover, mouseevent

I'm working on this website http://ba.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/table.html
and as you can see I've a table. What I need is to link every single row of the table to a different image on the right(the pink one) when you go with the mouse over the row. In my case a have a **col-md-8** with the table and a **col-md-4** with a picture. I want to change that picture when you go with mouse over the single row on the left.

Is possible to do?

Comment: So you want to change the pink place holder when some hoovers over a table row with the corresponding image? I think you need javascript for that, are you familiar with that?

Comment: @martijnn2008 basically i want to change the picture on the right when you hover a table row on the left cause i have different images for different rows. And no... i'm not familiar... :/

Comment: I don't think it's possible without it, so try to read up on the bassics of [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/).

Answer (score 0):

I could give you some advice to use a small jquery script, but I need to know if your table is static or dynamic.

I will edit this post later after you answer.

Comment: What do you mean for "dynamic"? Is just responsive and what i need is something like a "tooltip" when you hove a row the picture on the right will change